# how to let Jmeter add test files as part of the load test

Tags: jmeter

My application is about uploading files and converting them.

How do I add those test files as part of the load test?

Is that by using variable and parameter?

Please share with me samples if there is.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of building a JMeter Test Plan is recording the requests using your browser and JMEter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

In order to be able to record the file upload event you need to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for more details if needed.

Once you have test plan "skeleton" you will be able to [parameterize file names/correlate dynamic parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)/etc.